# Sorting objects by multiple attributes

Tags: java

I've been working on something that requires me to sort objects (Soft drinks) by three attributes - `name (str)`, `colour (str)` and `volume (int)`.  I've researched around and found ways to order them by name and colour and volume separately, but is there a way to order them by all three?

By which I mean: For example, say there are four SoftDrink objects: Fanta Orange 500, Coke Red 500, Coke Silver 500 Fanta Orange 400.

The output I'm looking for would be:

> - 1) Coke Red 500
> - 2) Coke Silver 500
> - 3) Fanta Orange 400
> - 4) Fanta Orange 500

Sort by name first, then colour, then volume (ascending).

I'm using three Comparators currently: `nameComparator`, `colourComparator`, and `volumeComparator`, but each of them sorts the objects by name only, then by colour only, then by volume only.  Is it possible to sort according to multiple attributes with Comparator?

Comment: Hint: there was a nice presentation on that this summer: http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/D4_Wiedeking.pdf ... some German text on some of the foils, but mostly java source code examples. That thing takes lambdas and comparing stuff ... to the next level.

Comment: @GhostCat That link doesn't work for me :/ it just takes me to the home page.

Comment: Takes me to the home page too, but if you have the link feel free to post it.  Would definitely be interested in learning about comparing things in more detail :)

Comment: Now, thats weird. Try opening this page: http://2016.java-forum-stuttgart.de/de/Programm.html     and then search for "lambdas" ... and click that link there ("Vortrag"). Which is the same link that I posted above; and when I click in both occasions, it starts downloading.

Comment: Seems to work.  I'll give it a gander.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
drinks.sort(
      Comparator.comparing(Drink::getName).thenComparing(Drink::getColour).thenComparing(Drink::getVolume)
    );
```

Remember to have getters for your attributes (`getName`, `getColour` etc.). This is all you need, no need for any custom comparators or anything.

Comment: Last type is `int`, so you can use `thenComparingInt`, to avoid some boxing.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alex!

Answering your question about ordering entities by multiple attributes with comparator here's the link to java tutorial on object ordering:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

In particular there is an example of Comparator which first compares objects by date and then (in case of equality) compares them by number:

```
static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = 
                                        new Comparator<Employee>() {
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        int dateCmp = e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate());
        if (dateCmp != 0)
            return dateCmp;

        return (e1.number() < e2.number() ? -1 :
               (e1.number() == e2.number() ? 0 : 1));
    }
};
```

It's easy to apply this pattern to your case:

```
static final Comparator<SoftDrink> DRINKS_ORDER = new Comparator<SoftDrink>() {
    public int compare(SoftDrink d1, SoftDrink d2) {
        int nameCmp = d1.getName().compareTo(d2.getName());
        if (nameCmp != 0) {
            return nameCmp;
        }
        int colorCmp = d1.getColor().compareTo(d2.getColor());
        if (colorCmp != 0) {
            return colorCmp;
        }
        return d1.getVolume() < d2.getVolume() ? -1 : (d1.getVolume() == d2.getVolume() ? 0 : 1);
    }
};
```

Be sure to check values for nulls (if necessary) before calling compareTo method.